# How to store variable data in PDF after close?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm coding a PDF application in Acrobat using Javascript, and need the ability to store data in the background after the document is closed.

For example, if I set the value of the array `arr[0] = "myData";` (and let's just say that happens dynamically) when I close and reopen the PDF the value of `arr[0]` will return as `undefined`.

Is there another way to store data that saves with the PDF file that I can call back using javascript? I'd ideally like to do this in the background rather than filling a dummy text box with a bunch of text.

Thanks!

Comment: I googled this: http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/get-and-set-pdf-metadata-from-acrobat-javascript

Comment: This could work, but only accepts a single value per key. It doesn't seem to have support for storing arrays or objects.

I'm in the process of looking into Data objects: http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html&accessible=true

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that will work.

I incorporated Diodeus's link to editing Acrobat metadada along with a JSON object found here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

I just took the object I wanted and used the Stringify method (of the JSON object) to turn it into a JSON string. I then stored it in a meta variable (Diodeus's link).

To get it back into an object, I used the parse method (of the JSON object). Works like a charm!